# Having issues with the steps inside my main loop

Tags: java

Basically this program takes in an object arraylist of new Anime episodes, downloads them to a folder that utorrent will auto detect .torrent files in and download them as output to another folder while also outputting the .torrent to a "finished" directory. This program will Download, Wait for download to be done, rename and move the file, then check for next and start over with next.

I'm having an issue though, with more than one item to be downloaded it for some reason will just skip the "wait for download && rename/move file" and just end after first itteration works fine, it still downloads the actual item 2 file but just ignores the rest of the do/while after the beginning and prints out my debug sysoutprint's in the actual code indicating the program is going thru the steps but ignoring the do/while after the first time around. I've tried initiating the Mover and DownloadProgressTracker inside each itteration instead of before and still same situation. I'm sure using thread/volatile booleans i could make it work but would rather avoid it for now.

TestingMain.java

```
public class TestingMain
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
    }
}
```

Program.java

```
public class Program
{
    private final String Torrent_Working_Dir = "torrent working path";
    private final String Torrent_Finished_Dir = "torrent finished path";
    private final String Completed_Downloads_Dir = "output files of torrent path";

    public boolean Downloading_Still;
    public boolean Renaming_Still;

    private ArrayList<ToDownload> Items_To_Download = new ArrayList<ToDownload>();
    private ToDownload dls;
    private Mover mv;
    private DownloadProgressTracker Prog;

    public Program()
    {
        FillArray();
        PrintArray();
        DownloadThese(Items_To_Download);
    }

    public void FillArray() // putting fake elements into array as examples
    {
        dls = new ToDownload("AnimeOne", "linkOne", "RawAnimeOne", "formatedTitleOne", "DirOne");
        Items_To_Download.add(dls);
        dls = new ToDownload("AnimeTwo", "linkTwo", "RawAnimeTwo", "formatedTitleTwo", "DirTwo");
        Items_To_Download.add(dls);
    }

    public void PrintArray() // debugging
    {
        for(ToDownload t : Items_To_Download)
        {
            System.out.println("Title: " + t.getTitle() + "\nLink: " + t.getLink() + "\nRaw: "
                    + t.getRaw() + "\nFinal: " + t.getFinal() + "\nRoot: " + t.getRoot() + "\n\n");
        }
    }

    public void DownloadThese(ArrayList<ToDownload> dls)
    {
        ArrayList<ToDownload> temp;
        int target = dls.size(); // the amount of downloads to do
        int count = 0; // keeps track of how many are done
        mv = new Mover();
        Prog = new DownloadProgressTracker(Torrent_Finished_Dir);
        do
        {
            for(ToDownload dl : dls)
            {
                // step 1
                // download the torrent file into torrent working dir
                //
                Downloading_Still = true;
                Renaming_Still = true;
                try
                {
                    // step 2
                    // wait for utorrent to finish downloading and put the torrent into it's finished dir
                    do{Prog.waitForDownload(this);}while(Downloading_Still != false);

                    // step 3
                    // rename and move the file to the folder it belongs in from utorrents file output folder
                    do{mv.checkExist(this, dl.getTitle(), dl.getFinal(), Completed_Downloads_Dir, dl.getRoot());}while(Renaming_Still != false);
                }
                catch(IOException e)
                {

                }
                // step 4
                // count = 0, count++, count now = 1
                count++;
            }
        }
        // step 5
        // if count is not == target go back to step 1
        while(count != target);
    }

}
```

Yes I've left out the actual Downloading portion. It's not the issue in this case. Just takes info from current dl in dls and downloads .torrent file into specified directory.

DownloadProgressTracker.java

```
public class DownloadProgressTracker
{
    private String Path;
    private File Root;
    private File[] Root_Folder;

    private boolean Still_Downloading;

    public DownloadProgressTracker(String path)
    {
        Path = path;
    }

    public void waitForDownload(Program p) throws IOException
    {
        Still_Downloading = true; // set true before checking
        Root = new File(Path); // initiate folder step 1
        Root_Folder = Root.listFiles(); // initiate folder step 2
        while(Root_Folder.length == 0) // if folder is empty just update folder
        {
            Root_Folder = Root.listFiles(); // update folder until not empty
        }
        int length = Root_Folder.length; // so that next while can be updated by first
        while(length != 0) // if folder contains something
        {
            for(File f : Root_Folder) // for each File in folder do something
            {
                try{f.delete();}catch(Exception e){} // delete the file
            }
        }
        Still_Downloading = false;
        p.Downloading_Still = Still_Downloading; // return false
    }
}
```

ToDownload.java

```
public class ToDownload
{
    private String Title, Link, Raw_Title, Final_Title, Root_Folder;

    public ToDownload(String title, String link, String raw, String finalT, String root)
    {
        Title = title;
        Link = link;
        Raw_Title = raw;
        Final_Title = finalT;
        Root_Folder = root;
    }

    public String getTitle()
    {
        return Title;
    }

    public String getLink()
    {
        return Link;
    }

    public String getRaw()
    {
        return Raw_Title;
    }

    public String getFinal()
    {
        return Final_Title;
    }

    public String getRoot()
    {
        return Root_Folder;
    }
}
```

Mover.java

```
public class Mover
{
    private File from, to, Finished_Dls;
    private File[] start;

    private String toDest, toOther, fromDest;

    private boolean Moving_File, Renaming_File, Renaming_Still;

    public void checkExist(Program p, String Title, String finalTitle, String FromDest, String ToDest)
    {
        Finished_Dls = new File(FromDest);
        start = Finished_Dls.listFiles();
        toDest = ToDest + "\\";
        toOther = toDest;
        fromDest = Finished_Dls.getPath() + "\\";
        Renaming_Still = true;
        Moving_File = true;
        Renaming_File = true;

        for(File f : start)
        {
            if(f.getName().contains(Title))
            {
                fromDest += f.getName();
                toDest += f.getName();
                do{MoveFileTo(fromDest, toDest);}while(Moving_File);
                do{RenameFile(toOther, toDest, finalTitle);}while(Renaming_File);
            }
        }
        Renaming_Still = false;
        p.Renaming_Still = Renaming_Still;
    }

    public void MoveFileTo(String from, String to)
    {
        this.from = new File(from);
        this.to = new File(to);
        try
        {
            Files.copy(this.from.toPath(), this.to.toPath());
            this.from.delete();
            Moving_File = false;
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Failed To Move File");
        }
    }

    public void RenameFile(String from, String to, String finalTitle)
    {
        this.from = new File(to);
        this.to = new File(from + "\\" + finalTitle);
        try
        {
            this.from.renameTo(this.to);
            Renaming_File = false;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Failed To Rename File");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it just freeze up the loop once waitForDownload is called the second time until the folder is no longer empty?

Comment: i'll try using local vars inside the MoveFileTo instead to see if it works

Comment: it will only grab the first thing in the arraylist of downloads before executing, never seen it go for more than one at a time before that comes around, but yes what you said before made me realize that making the vars local would solve the issue and it did so thank you lol

Comment: after changing Mover.waitForDownload and deleting 2 things that were available in the feed to be downloaded i ran the program and it works great, now onto another issue i have just encountered for the first time. Will try to fix this myself if i can't will be posting if stuck again lol